# Edit Data-table in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, primefaces

**Note:** I am using Spring MVC 3.2 and JSP.

I know that [**this**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193068/Adding-data-management-CRUD-functionalities-to-the) is really good example to eidt a row of table in JSP by using JQuery/Javascript ... But I donot want to use JQuery and/or Javascript. I have done lot of work in JSF where I donot need any Jquery to edit or delete a row from datatable.

1) Is there a way to do CRUD JSP-Datatable without using JQuery/Javascript like people use Primefaces and richfaces ?

2) How to use AJAX in JSP dataable without using JQuery/Javascript like I can use AJAX in Primefaces/richfaces using JSF ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both of your questions is that you can't do this without using javascript. In fact, Primefaces also uses jQuery (the components are based on jQuery ui) under the hoods, just inspect the primefaces main jar and you'll find it all there.

What makes Primefaces such a good framework is that the integration is so seamless, that you mainly don't have to deal with javascript, even to the point that you're not aware that is in fact there.

Your best option is to learn a good JS ui component framework, or stick with a good JSF implementation

Comment: So Is there no framework that hides the JQuery implementation and uses JSP .. ?

Comment: Hard to tell with so many frameworks around. You can try with Struts 2, the view is primarily based on JSP, and they offer a UI taglib (also backed by js)